# SQL Query to join 3 tables with the same FK

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

Say I have 3 tables:

1. Product (Id, ProductNumber)
2. Quotation (Id, QuotationNumber, ProductId, OrderId)
3. Order (Id, OrderNumber, ProductId)

Not all Quotation has Order, not all Order has Quotation.

The output I'd like to achieve is:

```
Product No | Quotation No | Order No
     *            *             *
     *            *
     *                          *
```

Currently I can achieve this using 2 queries combined into 1. 
Is there any way I can use 1 query only?

```
SELECT Product.ProductNumber, Quotation.QuotationNumber, Order.OrderNumber
FROM Product
JOIN Quotation ON Product.Id = Quotation.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Order ON Product.Id = Order.ProductId AND Quotation.OrderId = Order.Id

UNION

SELECT Product.ProductNumber, NULL, Order.OrderNumber
FROM Product
JOIN Order ON Product.Id = Order.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Quotation ON Product.Id = Quotation.ProductId AND Order.Id = Quotation.OrderId
WHERE Quotation.Id IS NULL
```

UPDATE:

1. If the Product does not have Quotation nor Order, don't show.
2. Quotation and Order has a link as specified in the Quotation table.

Example:

```
Product:
P1
P2
P3
P4
P5

Quotation: 
Q1 | P1 | O1
Q2 | P2 | O2
Q3 | P3 | NULL

Order:
O1 | P1
O2 | P2
O3 | P3
O4 | P4
O5 | NULL

Output:
P1 | Q1   | O1
P2 | Q2   | O2
P3 | Q3   | NULL
P3 | NULL | O3
P4 | NULL | O4
```

My problem by combining into 1:

1. If Quotation and Order is not linked up, Q3 and O3 will be shown in 1 row, which is incorrect.
2. But if they are linked up, only the first 2 rows will be shown.

That's why I had to split it into 2. But I'm just wondering if it's possible with 1.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: According to your example, you need to add an `ORDER BY ProductNumber` at the last.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product.ProductNumber, Quotation.QuotationNumber, Order.OrderNumber
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Quotation ON Product.Id = Quotation.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Order ON Product.Id = Order.ProductId
```

Comment: @vincent007: This query will select all `productNumber`,`QuotationNumber`(if any),`OrderNumber`(if any). Isn't that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes correct. But if the product does not have quotation nor order, then don't show. This one is simple, just need to add WHERE clause. Another thing is that it doesn't show me those orders without quotation since you link Quotation and Order in the ON part. But if we remove this link, then those with Quotation and Order won't be linked up.

Comment: Added sample. Still can't. Your query will show Q3 together with O3, which is not correct.

Comment: @vincent007: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @vincent007: Add the column names to your example in question.

Comment: @vincent007: You use `productid`,`productNumber` in the query. I cant see them in your example.

Comment: It's just to make it easier. Each table has Id as PK.

Comment: @vincent007: But you select `p.ProductNumber`. Thats why I am asking you to provide the example with column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.Id, q.Id quotation_id, o.Id order_id
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON p.Id = o.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Quotation q ON p.Id = q.ProductId AND q.OrderId IS NOT NULL  
WHERE NOT (q.Id IS NULL AND o.Id IS NULL)
UNION
SELECT p.Id, q.Id quotation_id, NULL
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Quotation q ON p.Id = q.ProductId AND q.OrderId IS NULL
WHERE q.Id IS NOT NULL;
```

As the names of columns was not defined, see please the sqlfiddle file too
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbc1e/13

Comment: Nope, still not what I wanted. It's showing O3 and Q3 in 1 row.